# React - jest test returns API token error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test, but I get the following error: "API: unable to fetch api token." I tried using `shallow` instead of `mount` but it returns the same error.

```
describe('CreateTemplateModal', () => {
  let props, el
  const modal = function () {
    if (!el) el = mount(<CreateTemplateModal {...props} />)
    return el
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      onSubmit: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
    }
    el = undefined
  })

  it('calls onSubmit when create template button is clicked', () => {
    const el = modal().setState({
      title: 'new template',
      jurisdiction: 'nsw',
      description: 'random',
    })
    el.find('#create-template-btn').simulate('submit')
    expect(props.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: could you please add the code for `CreateTemplateModal` or at least the part where `onSubmit` is called

Comment: in unit testing it's common way to mock all except module currently under testing. it also mean mocking API calls. see examples in the docs' [Mock Functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are mocking onSubmit function, i suppose api is not called in onSubmit function or after `#create-template-btn` is clicked.
As you have not shared `CreateTemplateModal` code, I suggest check constructor or `render()` function in `CreateTemplateModal` component. There is definitely a call has been made for token API